# How to make a vertical up table heading like one on the screenshot attached using html and css or bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The desired output is as on the screenshot, I have tried to do it with bellow code but not really getting the desired output. Please assist me.
[image]

**CSS**

```
.vertical-up-left {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: sideways-right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>Heading 1</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Heading 2</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <th>
        <div class="vertical-up-left"><b>LEFT DESIRED HEADING</b></div>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>Typical cell</td>
      <td>Typical cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Typical Cell cell</td>
      <td>Typical Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```